# Django сайт + динамическое обновление

Tags: python, django, postgresql, debian, python-3.x

Есть сайт на Django. На одной странице есть некий контент, например, набор картинок: `/path/to/img1.jpeg, /path/to/img2.jpeg` и т.д., пусть, всего 5 штук.

Картинки лежат на том же сервере, что и сайт. Необходимо при изменении извне картинки в директории обновить ее на сайте, без перезагрузки страницы. Что-то типа ajax. Лучше не по таймеру, а на лету.

Отлеживать хэш-сумму файла картинки? Или дату изменения?

Также была идея хранить путь к каждой картинке в бд в таблице, и подписаться на обновление таблицы (update записи).

Но как это можно реализовать на django?

PostgreSQL 9.4, Django 1.8.3, Python 3.4.2, Debian 8 Jessie, Apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте polling, ajax или websocket выбирать вам. Можно в эту связку добавить и торнадо, который отлично справится с этой задачей.

Comment: Нужно производить обновление именно при изменении картинок на сервере, т.е. ajax не совсем подходит, нужна постоянная подписка на событие или вроде того. Исходя из того, что объем контента небольшой, что целесообразнее использовать? Не хотелось бы городить сложную систему, т.к. сайт простой, а картинки могут обновляться, скажем, несколько раз в сутки, и обновлять сайт каждую секунду, т.е. 80 000 раз в сутки, как мне кажется, нецелесообразно...

Comment: Пытаюсь разобраться с websocket (socket.io + tornadio2 либо  sockjs + sockjs-tornado), дошел до python manage.py async_server и задумался, а как это связать с wsgi и apache2?

Comment: И опять-таки, будет использоваться одновременно два фреймворка - django и tornado, это немного странно) Или для решения подобной задачи это целесообразно?

Comment: торнадо о джанге может не знать совсем. Синхронизация 2 этих апликейшенов может происходить через redis. О том как это сделать есть много литературы и примеров связок. Не забывай что websocket коннект может оборваться.